# Failed to make int column separated by comma?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables which has role and another which has mapping of role and  permission. 
I have created following SQL for getting permissionids comma separated which is not existed into given permissionid strings

```
DECLARE @RoleToDelete VARCHAR(500), @Permission_Ids VARCHAR(400) = '1,2,5,6,8'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500) 
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @RoleToDelete = coalesce(@RoleToDelete + '','', '''') + CAST(a.PermissionId AS VARCHAR)
FROM (SELECT PermissionId from [dbo].[RolePermissions] where RoleId = 11063 and PermissionId not in (' + @Permission_Ids +')) a'
EXECUTE @SQL
PRINT @RoleToDelete
```

Above code will return permission numbers which is not mentioned in @Permission_Ids string for role 11063.

I am getting following error

```
The name 'SELECT @RoleToDelete = coalesce(@RoleToDelete + ',', '') + CAST(a.PermissionId AS VARCHAR)
FROM (SELECT PermissionId from [dbo].[RolePermissions] where RoleId = 11063 and PermissionId not in (1,2,5,6,8)) a' is not a valid identifier.
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't yell in all caps as they are noise and will likely deprive you from good answers.

Comment: Is there a reason for dynamic SQL, maybe you could build these lists using table variables instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the routine `sp_executesql`.  This allows you to return values back from a dynamic SQL statement.  I think the following will work:

```
DECLARE @RoleToDelete VARCHAR(500) = '', @Permission_Ids VARCHAR(400) = '1,2,5,6,8';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @RoleToDelete = coalesce(@RoleToDelete + '','', '''') + CAST(a.PermissionId AS VARCHAR)
FROM (SELECT PermissionId from [dbo].[RolePermissions] where RoleId = 11063 and PermissionId not in (' + @Permission_Ids +')) a';

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@RoleToDelete varchar(8000) OUTPUT', @RoleToDelete = @RoleToDelete OUTPUT;

PRINT @RoleToDelete;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very subtle distinction between two ways of running sql using `EXECUTE`. Running:

```
EXECUTE @SQL
```

tries to run a stored procedure whose name is in `@SQL`. Running:

```
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

will run the actual SQL contained in `@SQL`. Switch to the latter to resolve your issue; this may throw another error related to your syntax, but that should be easier to fix.

Comment: This is discussed further over on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@RoleToDelete".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: Have a read of that Technet article. To quote, 'The EXEC() session can't see the variable, because it was declared in the calling session.'. More specifically, have a read of the section titled "Capturing results of EXEC()".

Comment: It may be that `EXEC` is the wrong function for what you need, and another approach may be more suitable.